# Method to find substring

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that in python there is a `in` operator which can used to check whether any sub-string or char is present in a string or not. I want to do this by checking each string (of length substring). Is the code below is the only way or is there any other way that I can achieve this?

```
m = "college"
s = "col"
lm = len(m)
ls = len(s)
f = 0

for i in range(lm):    
    if (i+ls) <= lm:
        if s == m[i:(i+ls)]:            
            global f
            f = 1
            break
if f:
    print "present"
else:
    print "not present"
```

What I am doing here is if my sub-string is `col`, my program checks the string of length sub-string with sub-string by moving from start to end of the main-string and returns true or not.

```
col
oll
lle
leg
ege
```

Comment: Are you looking for a better/different way to write the code, or for a smarter algorithm? Taken literally, the obvious "other way to achieve" the search is by just using the `in` operator. There are many ways to write the code differently, some of them pointed out in the responses. There are also smarter algorithms you can use to search for a substring, as pointed out in my answer. Please clarify.

Comment: I read the solutions down and it was what I expected...If u can provide me still more efficient algorithms plz do say bro it will be useful for me....

Comment: My answer does exactly that, but you'll need to code them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
In [1]: m = 'college'

In [2]: s = 'col'

In [3]: if any(m[i:i+len(s)] == s for i in range(len(m)-len(s)+1)):
   ...:     print 'Present'
   ...: else:
   ...:     print 'Not present'
   ...:     
Present
```

Where the `any` checks every substring of `m` of length `len(s)` and sees if it equals `s`. If so, it returns `True` and stops further processing (this is called 'short-circuiting' and is pretty similar to the `break` you have above).

Here is what the `any` piece would look like if we replaced it with a list comprehension and took out the equality comparison:

```
In [4]: [m[i:i+len(s)] for i in range(len(m)-len(s)+1)]
Out[4]: ['col', 'oll', 'lle', 'leg', 'ege']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a legitimate way to quickly implement a general substring search, but not the only one. More efficient algorithms include [Boyer-Moore string search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), [Knuth-Morris-Pratt search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), or search implemented with a [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

This is a large topic and your question does not make it clear what kind of information you are actually after. In case of Python, it is of course most effective to simply use the `in` operator and the related methods `str.find` and `str.index`, all of which deploy a [simplified Boyer-Moore](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `global` there. Also, you can do

```
In [1]: %paste
m = "college"
s = "col"

In [2]: 'not ' * all(s != m[i:i+len(s)] for i in range(1+len(m)-len(s))) + 'present'
Out[2]: 'present'
```

But actually you should of course just do `s in m`,

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem calls for a functional solution:

```
def strcomp(s, subs):
    if len(s) < len(subs):
        return False
    elif s[0:len(subs)] == subs:
         return True
    else:
        return strcomp(s[1:], subs)
```

You call recursively the `strcomp` function, each time with the "long" string - `s` losing its head until you either find `subs` in the first position or `s` becomes shorter than `subs`.